# Upgrading the AKS dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-dashboard

I am experimenting with the managed Azure Kubernetes service.  I was able to start with the standard 1.8.3 version and then upgraded to 1.9.6.  After the upgrade, I noticed that the Kubernetes dashboard still shows 1.8.3 as the version.  Is the dashboard supposed to be automatically upgraded or do I have to upgrade it manually?

Comment: If this is an experiment, perhaps you can downgrade and try again (ideally one minor release at a time)? I think it should be upgraded, but I'm not sure and can't access my own test cluster from here.

Comment: Hmm... good thought, but I am hoping not to do that.  I have seen references by the AKS team that these version jumps are allowed so I am guessing that I likely missed a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  I see that, as of today (4/20/2018), the [most recent version of the Kubernetes dashboard is still 1.8.3](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases) so it didn't need to be upgraded.